# how to not load entire script if viewport > X

Tags: jquery, viewport, tablet

My site has a jQuery zoom feature that is crashing on tablets. I think my best approach is to just remove it - it's not necessary. So I'd like to not have it load if the viewport is less than 980px, what can I do to this code to do that?

`<script src='js/jquery.zoom.js'></script>`

something like `<script>if viewport > 980px load 'script.js'</script>`?

Comment: These may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111131/best-way-of-dynamic-script-loading
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044573/using-jquery-to-get-size-of-viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AJAX function [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getScript):

```
if ($(window).width()>980) {
    $.getScript('js/jquery.zoom.js');
}
```

or simply write out the HTML, if you want it to load synchronously:

```
if ($(window).width()>980) {
    document.write("<script src='js/jquery.zoom.js'></script>");
}
```

Comment: These both seem to interfere with the other javascript on the page. I can't seem to place it right or even get it to work...

Comment: Can't help you there; you haven't shared the other JavaScript on the page.

Comment: It's got  alot of jquery. The site functions fine with just the `<script src='js/jquery.zoom.js'></script>` in it, but changing it to your suggestions messes everything up. Is `document.write` getting loaded before my functions using `document.load`?

Comment: I mean, shouldn't I be able to just swap out my line for your lines? Isn't it still being executed in the same order?

Comment: Again, I can't answer those questions without actually seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: I see. I think this is my problem: This script is for an image zoomer that uses the <div>'s ID like so: `<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pro_5030').zoom({on: 'click'});       
  });
 </script>`

I think this is being executed before the call you suggested...should I try setting a delay on it?

Comment: Probably that code is running before your plugin is downloaded. Why don't you try downloading the plugin all the time, and running the `.zoom()` method only if the browser is wide?

Comment: Sometimes it has multiple instances such as

`<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pro_9051').zoom({on: 'click'});
   $('#pro_9060b').zoom({on: 'click'});
   $('#pro_9091').zoom({on: 'click'});
   $('#pro_9094').zoom({on: 'click'});
   $('#pro_9099').zoom({on: 'click'});
   $('#pro_9105').zoom({on: 'click'});
   $('#pro_9107').zoom({on: 'click'});  
   
  });
 </script>`

could I still do that?

Comment: Yes, but you should probably be using a common class instead of zooming each ID individually.

Comment: By Jove that did the trick. Great idea man, thanks so much. BTW, I think I need have the ID's be clicked on and not classes, that's the way the image zoomer is set up. (http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) But thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        if(viewport>980){
            $.getScript('script.js');
        }
    });
```