# Load Element later, to improve page speed, but make it visible for SEO?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, pagespeed, billboard.js

I'm using billboard.js to display [this type of chart](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Chart.AreaChart) somewhere below the fold of my page.

Adding the billboard JS code is causing my mobile page speed to decrease from 90+ to 75-80.

My code is structured like this:

```
<!-- chart area -->
<div class="chart_holder">
    <div id="chart_area"></div>
</div>
...
...
...
<script src="/js/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/billboard.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">function drawChart(t){$(".chart_holder").show(),.........);</script>
```

Is there any way to make the chart load later, in order to solve google page speed issues like:

- Reduce JavaScript execution time
- Keep request counts low and transfer sizes small (Extra JS files are pretty big)
- Minimize main-thread work (Script Evaluation)

While at the same time, allow Search engine crawlers to understand that I'm providing added value to my visitors by displaying them data charts? It might be good for SEO so I don't want to hide the chart in a way that google can't see it for example.

**EDIT:**

This is how the chart is called:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax( {
        type:"GET", url:"chart/data.php", dataType:"json", data: {
            item_id: 'item'
        }
        , success:function(t) {
            void 0!==t.criteria?t.criteria[0].length<=2?$(".chart_holder").hide(): drawChart(t): $(".chart_holder").hide()
        }
        , error:function() {
            console.log("Data extraction failed")
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: As you don't state how you're calling drawChart, assuming you also have `<script>drawChart("t");</script>` somewhere, a guess might be to delay that with `<script>setTimout(function() { drawChart("t"); }, 10);</script>` or, as jquery, `<script>$(function() { drawChart("t"); })</script>`

Comment: I've edited my code. can you tell which line exactly should I modify? and will delaying it still be visible for SEO?

Comment: Careful. Any questions about SEO are off topic and will get your question closed. Stick to speed improvement and don't ask about SEO.

Comment: Your new code shows that your chart is **already** loading after the page has loaded (after a 2nd request to get the data).  So a request to load it *even* later makes no sense.

Comment: @Rob good catch - shows people never read the tags they add to their questions!

Comment: I read the tag and it is programming related - simply make sure that the crawler sees the content. its a factual question. the question is not whether it will be beneficial or not. Is there any other way then to increase page speed with this code?

Comment: "page speed to decrease from 90+ to 75-80" has no meaning by itself, I guess you mean in the stats from Google (which is meaningless for any other than Google). Please don't call me picky, page analysis scripts can behave very differently. Can you confirm on that point?

Comment: @Kaddath I elaborated in my question 3 bullet points of why the score decreases, and it revolves around the extra JS used by this billboard.js.

Comment: I hesitate to post as an answer because I haven't tested myself, but it seems [from a comment in an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411411/7393478) that since recently, a 1 sec timeout is necessary for it to work for Google. You can try to combine this answer (the load listener part) with [what's there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611714/delay-script-loading) to see if this works..

Comment: how will it differ from document ready?

Comment: Yeah sorry, you use jQuery while the OP in the question I answered wasn't. You can use document ready to lauch the `setTimeout` of 1000ms that will add the script and draw the chart, of course. In case of jQuery it can be simpler to load the script with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111131/best-way-of-dynamic-script-loading) then

Comment: Can you post it as solution? I don't understand how to modify my code

Comment: I added the code, please let me know if it works for Google page speed ;)

Answer (score 1):

**CAUTION: this is based on the assumption that Google page speed calculations will not count the script loading if it is delayed 1 second, I haven't verified myself. Google page speed calculation script may change in the future, be sure to test with and without the delay.**

NOTE: of course it can be damaging for user experience if your entire page display rely on the script. For the OP's problem, it seems acceptable.

The trick here is to use a timeout of 1000ms after page load to load the script and when done, display the chart:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //you may need to change URL to a full URL here (with 'http://domain.etc')
        $.getScript('/js/billboard.min.js', function() {
            //you probably can keep this in your <script> tag, put it here if you have 'X is undefined' errors coming from calls to billboard's stuff
            function drawChart(t){$(".chart_holder").show(),.........);
            //your ajax call and the chart display
            $.ajax( {
                type:"GET", url:"chart/data.php", dataType:"json", data: {
                    item_id: 'item'
                },
                success:function(t) {
                    void 0!==t.criteria?t.criteria[0].length<=2?$(".chart_holder").hide(): drawChart(t): $(".chart_holder").hide()
                },
                error:function() {
                    console.log("Data extraction failed")
                }
            } );
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

**ALSO**: It's not clear from the question if you need the 3 scripts in the code for the chart or only `billboard`. If you want to delay the 3 of them, you need to chain `getScript` calls like this:

```
$.getScript('/js/d3.v5.min.js', function() {
    $.getScript('/js/billboard.min.js', function() {
        $.getScript('/js/moment.min.js', function() {
            //the rest
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Minimizing http request

billboard.js provides a packaged version of `d3 + billboard.js`.

> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js

So, if you need to deal with file counts, deal with packaged version.

### Lazy rendering

From the `1.11.0` release, added new feature to delay chart rendering. (Internally it will hold the rendering process)

> https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#ChartOptions.LazyRender

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
  ...,
  render: {
    lazy: true,
    observe: false
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    // call '.flush()' at the point you want to be rendered
    chart.flush();
}, 1000);
```